# SignalR connectionData parameter is encoded twice in IE8

Tags: .net, webforms, signalr, webmethod, asp.net-4.5

On my production server I receive: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: %. Path '', line 0, position 0. This exception is thrown between 2-10 times a day and I cannot reproduce this at local.My production server is Windows Server 2008, IIS 7.5. My project is ASP.NET Application (Web forms) with .Net 4.5.
I use SignalR v.2.2.0 and offending url is http://example.com:8083/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=...&connectionData=%255B%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522signalrhub%2522%257D%255D ...

In javascript I use two session variables that can be changed between signal connect and disconnect events, so I use PageMethods to get them from session:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetSessionValue(string key)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session[key] == null || HttpContext.Current.Session[key].ToString() == "no")
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session[key].ToString();
    }
}
```

I use telerik's ScriptManger with the following references:

```
EnablePageMethods="true">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/json2.min.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="/signalr/hubs" />
            </Scripts>            
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

(I added reference to json2.min.js because of IE7).

My client-side code is the follow:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="SignalRCodeBlock" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {                    
            //$.connection.hub.logging = true;                    
            var proxy = $.connection.signalRHub;

            proxy.client.notifyNomUpdated = function (lastUpdateDate) {                        
                showLastUpdateDate(lastUpdateDate);
            };

            proxy.client.getLastUpdateFromSession = function () {                        
                PageMethods.GetSessionValue("UserNomUpdated", checkLastUpdateDate);                        
            };

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {                        
                PageMethods.GetSessionValue("CustomerID", checkCustomerID);
            });

            function checkCustomerID(customerID) {                       
                if (customerID != "") {
                    proxy.server.setGroupForCustomer(customerID);
                }
            }

            function checkLastUpdateDate(lastUpdateDate) {
                if (lastUpdateDate != "") {
                    showLastUpdateDate(lastUpdateDate);
                }
            }

            function showLastUpdateDate(lastUpdateDate) {
                $('#<%= LoadingImage.ClientID %>').addClass("displayNone") 
                $('#<%= ReadyImage.ClientID %>').removeClass("displayNone");
                var msg = 'Last updated on: ' + lastUpdateDate;
                $('#<%= UpdateLabel.ClientID %>').text(msg);
            }

        });

    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

After few hours expecting IIS logs I found that problem occurs only in IE8 -Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0) where transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5.

Thanks to the post in this link: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3319 in which is described totally the same problem I found that parameter connectionData is encoded twise. In my case the value of this parameter is:
connectionData=%255B%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522signalrhub%2522%257D%255D
but have to be:
connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22signalrhub%22%7D%5D,
which decoded is: [{"name":"signalrhub"}] where "signalrhub" is my hub name.
If anybody have idea how to solve this problem or how to contact with someone from the SignalR team why can help me, I would appreciate any suggestions.